# Using Babel to convert const pointing to arrow functions

Tags: javascript, express, babeljs

I'm creating an express application starter. Write now I'm struggling with configuring Babel to compile constants that points to arrow functions:

```
const initializeMiddleware = app => {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
};
```

Compilation finishes ok but when I try to run application I get following error:

```
TypeError: initializeMiddleware is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Projects/Starters/starters-node-express/public/app.js:21:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
```

Babel Configuration (.babelrc):

```
{
    "presets": [ "es2015", "es2016", "stage-1" ],
    "plugins": [ "transform-es2015-arrow-functions" ]
}
```

Compiled function has following structure:

```
var initializeMiddleware = function initializeMiddleware(app) {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
};
```

Can anyone help me to solve the issue?

Comment: What's incorrect about the compiled function? That is an accurate translation of what you originally wrote.

Comment: I think it should be converted to _var initializeMiddleware = function(app) { ... }_??

Comment: It could. It doesn't matter. It's just a named function expression rather than an anonymous function expression. `initializeMiddleware` still refers to a function in both cases. If you're getting the error you mentioned, you're either trying to access that function from a different scope or before it's been declared.

Comment: I guess you're write. [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions) But still it doesn't working

Comment: I'd have to see how you're using the function. Like I said, you're either using it in the wrong scope or before it's declared.

Comment: For the love of god write != right....

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I invoked the function before it was declared.